# Pass CSS id as a parameter in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a CSS id which shows a small red ball and a JAVASCRIPT function. I want to pass the CSS id as a parameter in the JavaScript function. I've seen a lot of tutorials but can't figure it out. Here are the codes:

CSS code

```
#projectile{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    left:176px;
    top: 486px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT code

```
function gofish(projectile_id){
var projectile = getElementbyId(projectile_id);
start_x = projectile.offset().left;
start_y = projectile.offset().top;

function init()
{ setTimeout("gofish('projectile')", 500); }
```

Comment: Do you have a `getElementbyId` function, or did you actually mean `document.getElementbyId`

Comment: And it looks like you're using jQuery from the `offset()` function ?

Comment: Open up the browser console, you'll find it useful to viewing error messages.

Comment: @adeneo, I tried with both `getElementbyId` and `document.getElementbyId` but nothing worked. And yes I'm using jquery offset function.

Comment: @user2611329 - I thought so, and I've posted an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you're using jQuery and that you want a jQuery object to use the [`offset()`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) method as no such method exists for plain DOM nodes

```
function gofish(projectile_id){
    var projectile = $('#' + projectile_id);
    var start_x = projectile.offset().left;
    var start_y = projectile.offset().top;
}

function init() { 
    setTimeout(function() {
        gofish('projectile');
    }, 500); 
}
```

Comment: this worked. Just it should be `projectile = $('#' + projectile_id);` instead of `var projectile = $('#' + projectile_id);`. Tnx, it helped a lot! :)

Comment: That would make the variable global, and you should generally avoid that, but  if it works it works. Happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

You have a few mistakes in your JavaScript.

- getElementById should have a capital 'b', and should be called against document.
- I think the offset properties you are look for are element.offsetLeft and element.offsetTop.
- You can define an anonymous function directly on setTimeout to call init(), exactly as adeneo has suggested.
- You will still need to call init() somewhere in order for it to run.

Here is updated JavaScript code:

```
function gofish(projectile_id) {
    var projectile = document.getElementById(projectile_id);
    start_x = projectile.offsetLeft;
    start_y = projectile.offsetTop;
}

function init() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        gofish('projectile');
    }, 500);
}

init();
```

And here is the code in action, so far: http://jsfiddle.net/JuvDX/

Answer (score 0):

This may help you little..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function myFunction(element)
{
alert(document.getElementById(element.id).value);
}
</script>
<style>
#para1
{
text-align:center;
color:red;
} 
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p id="para1" onclick="myFunction(this)" name="paragraph" >Hello World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```